# If $AXA^T = BXB^T$, does that mean $A = B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given square matrices $A$, $B$, if there exists a symmetric matrix $X$ with entries in $(0,1)$ such that
$$
AXA^T = BXB^T,
$$
does that imply $A = B$ ?

What about a specific condition, e.g. when $A, B$ are symmetric?

Sizes of $A, B$ necessarily have to be the same for the equation to be valid.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151845/discussion-on-question-by-pu239-if-axat-bxbt-does-that-mean-a-b); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.